# TailwindCSS animation doesn't work with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a list of pop messages in the right top part of the screen. On click this message goes away. Each popup message is a part of `slide-fade` Transition.

When I have only one popup component, the animation works, however with more than 1 the animation doesn't work. I would really appreciate if anyone can  help me out with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

**popup.vue**

```js
<template>
    <Transition name="slide-fade" @click="close">
        <div class="bg-green-100 opacity-95 rounded-lg py-5 px-6 mb-3 text-green-700 inline-flex items-center text-sm" role="alert">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="check-circle" class="w-8 h-8 mr-2 fill-current" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                <path fill="currentColor" d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zM227.314 387.314l184-184c6.248-6.248 6.248-16.379 0-22.627l-22.627-22.627c-6.248-6.249-16.379-6.249-22.628 0L216 308.118l-70.059-70.059c-6.248-6.248-16.379-6.248-22.628 0l-22.627 22.627c-6.248 6.248-6.248 16.379 0 22.627l104 104c6.249 6.249 16.379 6.249 22.628.001z"></path>
            </svg>
            {{ placeholder }}
        </div>
    </Transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'popupComponent',
    methods: {
        close () {
            this.$emit('close', this.arrIndex)
        }
    },
    props: {
        placeholder: String, 
        arrIndex: Number
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(.25,.59,.63,.92);
}

.slide-fade-enter-from,
.slide-fade-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(20px);
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

**App.vue**:

```js
<template>
  <div class="absolute z-10 right-0 p-2 max-w-md">
     <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-2 max-h-96 overflow-y-hidden">
        <popup v-for="(content, index) in popup_content.slice().reverse()" :key="index" @close="closePopup" :arrIndex="(popup_status.length-1) - index"  :placeholder="content"/>
     </div>  
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import popupComponent from './components/popup.vue'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      popup_content: ['Awesome!', 'Nice!'],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    closePopup(index) {
      this.popup_content.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },
  components: {
    'popup': popupComponent
  },
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because you use an index as a key.

You should not use `index` as a key of the `v-for` in your case, because you are altering the array. Use a unique, non-changing identifier, like an id or in your code example the content:

```
<popup v-for="(content, index) in popup_content.(...)" :key="content" ...>
```

Vue relies on the key to track changes in the DOM. With your `close` function, you delete an item from the array, e.g. if you close the first message, this causes the second message getting index 0, instead of 1. This can cause the strange behaviour you are experiencing. [See docs.](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key)

In your case it might be better to [generate a unique id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID) for each popup message when it is created. Your popup content then would be something like:

```
popup_content: [
   {
      id: 'e5803eab...', 
      text: 'Awesome!'
    }, 
    {
      id: '8396...', 
      text: 'Nice!'
     }
],
```

In your for loop you can use the id as a key:

```
<popup v-for="(popup, index) in popup_content.(...)" :key="popup.id" :placeholder="popup.text" ...>
```

And you can still use the index for other purposes.

Comment: What if I need to send in other props that rely on array indecies?

Comment: In what way do you mean by 'rely on array indecies'? DO you have an example?

Comment: I have added an example to my answer.